# Not able to save extra user Info screen

Tags: support

Just signed up using my google account on StackOverflow. Editing the user Info allowed my to change my user ID, but all the other information that was blank was not saved. I originally thought that it was because I typed the birth date in the wrong format, but trying again did not work either. I can't even figure out how to get back to the edit screen for user details now that I navigated away from it . . . so I can't check if the e-mail address was changed.

Comment: Your [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/2115987)

Comment: Yes, thanks, I meant the entire URI to the user edit screen, I found it under the notifications under the Stack drop down. I still don't see how to get there another way once that notification is deleted.

Comment: Click on your name at the top bar. That will get you to your profile page. There is an edit link to the right, above the gray info area.